# Redhat error while loading shared libraries: libkeyutils.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

Tags: rhel, libraries, shared-library

I just installed and am trying to start rpcbind on my redhat 7 machine. I'm new to linux so I'm having some trouble figuring out what to do next. I'm running all of these commands as the root user.

When I run rpcbind I get the following output:

```
Jan 07 09:44:28 sebilj systemd[1]: Starting RPC bind service...
**Jan 07 09:44:28 sebilj rpcbind[17902]: /sbin/rpcbind: error while loading shared libraries: libkeyutils.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied**
Jan 07 09:44:28 sebilj systemd[1]: rpcbind.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
Jan 07 09:44:28 sebilj systemd[1]: Failed to start RPC bind service.
Jan 07 09:44:28 sebilj systemd[1]: Unit rpcbind.service entered failed state.
Jan 07 09:44:28 sebilj systemd[1]: rpcbind.service failed.
```

So I checked and the library in question does exist and it has chmod set to 777 so full permissions.

I checked and this library is linking to a lib with the same name but a higher version, and this second lib also has full permissions:

```
ldconfig -v | grep libkeyutils.so.1
    libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.5
```

Finally I checked which libs rpcbind needs and it showed me the following:

```
ldd /sbin/rpcbind
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe2b731000)
libtirpc.so.3 => /lib64/libtirpc.so.3 (0x00007f4f06b43000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib64/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f4f06b1b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4f068fe000)
libwrap.so.0 => /lib64/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f4f066f3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4f06332000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f4f060e5000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f4f05e00000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f4f05bce000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f4f059c9000)
libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f4f057c4000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4f054c2000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f4f052b9000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f4f05094000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f4f04e6f000)
libgcrypt.so.11 => /lib64/libgcrypt.so.11 (0x00007f4f04bed000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f4f049e8000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f4f047ce000)
libdw.so.1 => /lib64/libdw.so.1 (0x00007f4f04586000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4f04382000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4f0416c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4f06f8a000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f4f03f52000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f4f03d43000)
**libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f4f03b3f000)**
libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f4f03939000)
libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f4f036d8000)
libelf.so.1 => /lib64/libelf.so.1 (0x00007f4f034c1000)
libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f4f032b1000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f4f0309b000)
```

From this I can see **libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f4f03b3f000)**. My assumption is that the higher version that libkeyutils.so.1 links to is causing the problem but I'm not sure how to resolve this since when searching for this lib it shows me the package that I already have installed. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I just want to add that Ijaz Khan's suggestion resolved the issue from me, I had a version issue when installing without Yum.

Comment: Remove/purge rpcbind  and re-install the pakage with yum